# getJdbcTemplate().query(query,args,rowmapper) query returns null

Tags: java, sql, spring

```
tsList = getJdbcTemplate().query(sqlQuery,args,
    new RowMapper() {
        public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        }
    });
```

I ran the sqlQuery in SQlmanagementstudio ,query is fine.

the problem is when result is null, i see no error but in log i see
"DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Should roll back transaction but cannot - no transaction available"

if result has data ,i have no problem.

please help , thanks in advance.

Comment: Why aren't you implementing mapRow method?

Comment: i have implemented it. " return rs.getInt(1);"